# How to generate XML feed with nested tags using Xpath Parser?

Tags: views, feeds

I have a XML file as below

```
<rss>
  <channel>
    <title>Channel Title</title>
    <description>Channel Description</description>
    <owner>
      <owner:name>Owner Name</owner:name>
      <owner:email>Owner Name</owner:email>
    </owner>
    <item>
      <title>Item 1 title</title>
      <author>Item 1 author</author>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>Item 2 title</title>
      <author>Item 2 author</author>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

In my Xpath parser settings, I gave `/rss/channel/item` as context and I am getting only the item title and item author into my node. How it is possible to add title,description and owner details into my node?. And I also want the same structured XML output using [Views data export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your context 1 level back.

context: `/rss/channel`

title: `title`

description: `description`

owner name: `owner/owner:name`

owner email: `owner/owner:email`

item title: `item/title`

item author: `item/author`